# how to connect dynamically enter data into database using laravel

Tags: database, laravel

I am trying store data that is entered dynamically from Post form into MySQL database in Laravel.

Purchase model

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Purchase extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=['clid,date,name,quantity,price,subTotal,grandtotal'];

```
public function setClideAttribute($input){
    $this->attributes['clid'] = $input ?  $input : null;
}
public function setDateAttribute($input){
    $this->attributes['date'] = $input ?  $input : null;
}
public function setNameAttribute($input){
    $this->attributes['name'] = $input ?  $input : null;
}
public function setQuantityAttribute($input){
    $this->attributes['quantity'] = $input ?  $input : null;
}
public function setPriceAttribute($input){
    $this->attributes['price'] = $input ?  $input : null;
}
public function setSubtotalAttribute($input){
    $this->attributes['subTotal'] = $input ?  $input : null;
}
public function setGrandtotalAttribute($input){
    $this->attributes['grandtotal'] = $input ?  $input : null;
}
```

}

PurchasesController

public
function store(Request $request) {

```
$this - > validate(request(), [
    'date' => 'required',
    'name' => 'required',
    'quantity' => 'required',
    'price' => 'required',
    'subTotal' => 'required',
    'grandtotal' => 'required'

]);

foreach($request - > get('purchases_details') as $Purchase) {
    $Purchase = new Purchase([
        'date' => $request - > get('date'),
        'name' => $request - > get('name'),
        'quantity' => $request - > get('quantity'),
        'price' => $request - > get('price'),
        'subtotal' => $request - > get('subtotal'),
        'grandtotal' => $request - > get('grandtotal')

    ]);
}
$purchase - > save();
return redirect() - > route('purchase.store') - > with('success', 'Data Added');

DB::table('purchases') - > insert($data);
echo "success";
```

}

The data entered in the form dynamically did not store in database

Comment: There are a few areas for improvement in your code: you don't need a set for every attribute only for special cases, you already have a $request variable but you're passing a method in your validation call, also it looks like you have an array of purchase details but you are only saving outside the foreach, which won't save anything because all the objects will be out of scope at that time, please review https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018 for a better understanding of how to work properly with Laravel models and collections.